# Finding images on page that have a specific filename with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I need to do a check on a page to check if certain images have loaded ie. not returned 404. If they arent available I want to replace the image with a default images.

I am aware I can assign an onerror handler to the images.

Firstly I need to use a selector to find all the images that have a source which contains the following image name -> /folder/Product_1234_P.jpg OR /folder/Product_9876_Q.gif

Any ideas how I can create a high performance selector that I can use to find such images so that I can check if the images loaded, if not replace the image name with: Product_Default_P.jpg or Product_Default_Q.gif

Any help or advice would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the image's [error handler](http://api.jquery.com/error/) and the [attribute contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) like so:

```
$("img[src*=Product]").error(function() {
    $(this).attr('src', 'notfound.jpeg');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, think I may have not explained myself fully. The name of the image is dynmaic with only the word PRODUCT being constant. So could be Product_123_P.jpg or Product_8844_D.gif. The only constant is its structure ie. Product underscore number underscore letters extension

Comment: Thanks for that - I need to run this on most of my pages so need it to be performance efficient as possible - is this the case? Also I want to bind it using the live function so that not only it will handle page elements but also if a modal is triggered which has such images. Any ideas??

Comment: I wouldn't suggest using a wildcard match on image src attributes if you have hundreds of images. Can't you assign the images of interest a class, e.g. `<img class="product" src="something"/>` and the change the selector (in the above answer) to `img.product`?

Comment: @Niall this will be very performant and more importantly is a super clean solution. I recommend using this solution. The wildcard selector is actually faster than the starts with or ends with attribute selectors.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('img[src*="substring"]')
```

It's an attribute selector. Check it out http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

Answer (score 1):

I guess you mean something like

```
$("img[src^=/folder/Product_][src$=_P.jpg]")
```

i.e. "Find all img with a src starting with "/folder/Product_" and ending with "_P.jpg".

Comment: I don't think it's too expensive. The DOM objects can be fetched using getElementByTagName and the string matching is cheap. Can be used with .live(), however you have to choose the event you want to bind your function to.